# How to find $P(X>x)$ when the density is known but the integral does not seem to converge

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, improper-integrals

I am trying to evaluate
$$P(X>x) = \int_x^{\infty }  t^{\kappa } \exp{\left(-\rho t^{\alpha\kappa + 1}\right)} \, dt$$
where $\kappa$, $\rho$ and $\alpha$ are all constants.
I have tried some substitutions, integrating by parts to solve the integral, but it did not seem to converge.

I also tried to compute the laplace transform, inverse Fourier transform of the density using Mathematica, but it was n't able to work it out.

After having spent 6-7 hours trying to solve this I am still hopelessly stuck.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What did you spend "6-7 hours" at, exactly? Did you note that the RHS cannot be P(X>x) for every x, for any random variable X?

Comment: @Did No I did not notice anything like that. Can you please explain more why it can not be?

Comment: To begin with, P(X>0) might be greater than 1...

Comment: @Did I think what you are getting at is that in order to compute this probability I need to rewrite the rhs as 1 - the integral with lower limit negative infinity going to x, using the complement rule. Is that correct ?

Comment: No. More simply, the function which is being integrated is not a PDF in general.

Comment: @Did Why is not a pdf ?

Comment: See previous comment. (Do you know what a PDF is, in general?)

Comment: I can not be bothered with your one liners, if you can not bothered to type details then please leave my forum threads alone.

Comment: Which details are missing? If "P(X>0) might be greater than 1" does not ring a bell, what could? (And let us leave aside the rather ridiculous considerations in your last comment, shall we?)

Comment: Then you might want to mention in the question the regime you have in mind, ensuring that P(X>0) is not greater than 1. If P(X>0)<1, this means there is a Dirac delta at x=0? (FYI, I just flagged your last comment.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try the substitution $u=t^{\alpha\kappa+1}$? As far as I see, you get then something like $k\cdot u^{\beta}\exp(-\rho u)$ ($k,\beta$ constants) as integrand, the integral is then similar to the incomplete Gamma function.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function

Hope that it helps.

Answer (score 1):

As answered by Karl $$\int  t^{\kappa } \exp{\left(-\rho t^{\alpha\kappa + 1}\right)} \, dt=-\frac{t^{\kappa +1} \left(\rho  t^{\alpha  \kappa +1}\right)^{-\frac{\kappa
   +1}{\alpha  \kappa +1}} \Gamma \left(\frac{\kappa +1}{\alpha  \kappa +1},t^{\alpha
    \kappa +1} \rho \right)}{\alpha  \kappa +1}$$ where appears the incomplete gamma function.

This can also write $$\int  t^{\kappa } \exp{\left(-\rho t^{\alpha\kappa + 1}\right)} \, dt=-\frac{t^{\kappa +1} E_{\frac{(\alpha -1) \kappa }{\alpha  \kappa +1}}\left(t^{\alpha
    \kappa +1} \rho \right)}{\alpha  \kappa +1}$$ where appears the exponential integral function.